# Domain set notation for axes in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, notation, analytic-functions

I am analyzing a function $f(x+jy)$ in the complex plane, and it is differentiable if and only if $x = 0$ or $y = 0$, i.e. it is differentiable on the imaginary and real axes. What would be the proper way to then denote the domain on which the function is differentiable?

My intuition says that I can state the domain of the derivative as $\mathbb{R} \cup \mathbb{I}$ , i.e. $z$ is an element of either the set of reals or the set of imaginaries.

Is this the correct notation? Or is there a more appropriate way to state the domain?

I appreciate the assistance, thank you!

Comment: I think the function cannot be analytic on the set. If it is analytic at a point $z_0$, then it is differentiable on some neighborhood $N(z_0, r)$ for some $r>0$, then it is analytic on the neighborhood. In particular, a function is analytic on an open set.

Comment: @Aidan Boyko The notation $\mathbb{I}$ isn't very standard - as far as my experience goes, at least - and not too badly needed either, $\mathrm{i}\mathbb{R}$ suffices! Therefore you could simply say that the domain of derivability is $\mathbb{R} \cup \mathbb{R}\mathrm{i}$.

Comment: @Riemann ah I see, was attempting to back engineer the conditions for harmonic functions to determine the set on which the function is analytic, I should have reviewed the definition. Disregarding the point about the analytic domain, would the notation still be valid for the domain of the derivative? I appreciate the response, thank you

Comment: @ΑΘΩ I see, thank you for the clarification! Have a great day :D

Comment: @AidanBoyko Glad to have been of assistance, likewise to you my friend!